# Sanity check on limit problem

Tags: limits

I'm second guessing myself on limit problem. Is this all ok using continuity of log & exp + calculus of limits inside of log to get to 2/3 ?

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{1}{2^x}+\frac{2x+1}{3x+7})^x=exp\lim_{x\to\infty}ln(\frac{1}{2^x}+\frac{2x+1}{3x+7})^x=exp \lim_{x\to\infty}xln(\frac{1}{2^x}+\frac{2x+1}{3x+7})=$$$$exp\lim_{x\to\infty}xln(\frac{2}{3})=\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{2}{3})^x=0$$

Comment: Tip: type `\exp` and `\ln` instead of `exp` and `ln`

Comment: The *argument* is not correct. A version of it would show that $(1+1/x)^x$ has limit $1$. But the exponential/log part is OK.

Comment: However, the limit is indeed $0$. This can be shown by Squeezing.

Comment: I thought since I don't get 1 and the log doesn't evaluate as zero makes this ok - if not how am I supposed to tackle this properly?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think the argument is correct. In the third equality is the only step that is not argued by continuity. In this case he is using that $\lim[f(x)g(x)]=\lim f(x)\lim g(x)$ whenever it is not an indeterminate case. I would have put and intermediate step $exp\left[\lim_{x\to\infty}x\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{1}{2^x}+\frac{2x+1}{3x+7}\right)\right]$ to make it more clear.

Comment: @Pp..: What makes it not correct is exactly what you pointed out. Perhaps OP would have recognized that if the log is $0$ there is an issue. But an error at this stage is so common that in evaluating, one cannot assume that would have happened.

Comment: @AndréNicolas OK